# Excel SUMIFS multiple columns plus extra criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a formula that sums every nth column (where column name is 'value') and it works great:

```
=SUMIFS($B2:$CDF2,$B$1:$CDF$1,$D$1)
```

The problem is I need to add an additional criteria to only sum the columns when the time is greater than x (e.g. 12pm).  The problem is the time values vary within an individual column (see example below) so I can't just start the sumifs from a later range.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on your question and made some adaptations providing answers for sum of values when time is greater than 12 pm. The time is not in the correct 12 hour format.
Kindly use this formula `=SUM(IF((--ISNUMBER($B2:$L2)*--($B2:$L2<1)*--($B2:$L2>TIMEVALUE("12:00:00 PM"))),$C2:$M2,0))`
It should be entered in cell A2 using Ctrl + Shift + Enter for array formulas and populated downward

For this formula to work properly, please enter your data as shown below

[Observe the Corrected 12 Hour Date Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC2sA.png)

In any case where you are not in control of how the data is generated, kindly give me a feedback

Comment: I don't understand it but it works exactly as described.  Thank you for you help.